# What should I do in order to retain the `TextView` value in Android?

Tags: android

I have two text views on my home page of the app. I have two buttons which   launches new activities. I am taking the values of text view from the two  respective activities and using intent to pass data back to the main activity. 
      But when I do so only the current text view value is displayed. What should I do to display both at the same time?

## MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {


       private static String 
    MESSAGE_KEY="com.example.kjsce.budgetinyourpocket.message_key";
    private static String MESSAGE_KEY1="com.example.kjsce.budgetinyourpocket.message_key1";
    private TextView textView;
    private  TextView  textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String message=intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY);





        /*String t1=message;
        int t11=Integer.parseInt(t1);
        int t11add=0;
        t11add=t11+t11add;

        String hello=Integer.toString(t11add);*/
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.expense);
        textView.setText(message);


        Intent intent1=getIntent();
        String message1=intent1.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY1);

        textView1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.income);
        textView1.setText(message1);





        //textView.setText(hello);
        textView1.setText(message1);
    }




    public void expense(View view)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void income(View view)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Main3Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

### Main2Activity

```
 public void send(View view)
{
    amount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amt);
    String message=amount.getText().toString();
    Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
       i.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY,message);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

### Main3Activity

```
        public void sendd(View view)
{
    amount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amt);
    String message1=amount.getText().toString();
    Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY1,message1);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

`

Comment: I didn't get exact problem, if you aware of onActivityResult, start new Activity as a startActivityForResult instead of startActivity.

Comment: post all java code file

Comment: Try to use sharedPreference..

Comment: @ND1010_  please have a look at it!

Comment: it means you telling that when you click on to Main2Activity's button the call MainActivity and it will print Main3Activity's textValue and also print Main2Activity's value?

Comment: @RadhikaObhan check my post answer  go though it.....if any query related to that free to tel . -)

Answer (score 0):

use shared prefernce for set and get data from both activity and set it to main activiy.

set preference

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("key1", value1);
            editor.putString("key 2", value 2);           
            editor.commit();
```

get preference

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // then you use
  String yourVaue1 =  prefs.getString("Key1","");
  String yourVaue2 =  prefs.getString("Key2","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) to run the activity which triggers [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) right after it finishes so you can get your desired data from another activity

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_1 = 1, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_2 = 2;
    TextView textView1, textView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    }

    public void expense(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_1);
    }

    public void income(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_1) {
            String textValue = data.getStringExtra("textview_value");
            textView1.setText(textValue);

        } else if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_2) {
            String textValue = data.getStringExtra("textview_value");
            textView2.setText(textValue);
        }
    }
}
```

### Activity1.java

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_1 = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

        String textValue = "Something_from_activity_1";
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("textview_value", textValue);
        setResult(ACTIVITY_REQUEST_1, resultIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.streak.textactivity.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Activity_1_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="expense"
            android:text="Launch Activity 1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Activity_2_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="income"
            android:text="Launch Activity 2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its NOT working.Now the data is not getting displayed while returning back to the activity.

Comment: did you check wether the `onActivityResult` method is being triggered or not? are you sure that you have returned a string type from the sub activity?

Answer (score 0):

**you should use sharePreference**
If you know about sharefreference click [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference)  or click [www.tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

I have been solve your problem Just Going through **my steps** :-)

**Strp1:** *Activity1.xml and activity1.java*

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ncrypted.demorecyclerviewsubitems.Activity1">

    <EditText
        android:hint="Amount1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:id="@+id/etAmount1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="sendAmount1"
        android:id="@+id/btnSendAmount1"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String PREF_NAME = "prefName";
private final static String PREF_KEY = "prefKeyActivity1";
SharedPreferences sharedPref;
EditText etAmount1;
Button btnSendAmount1;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPref.edit();
    etAmount1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmount1);
    btnSendAmount1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendAmount1);

}

public void sendAmount1(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    if (etAmount1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter amount!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        editor.putString(PREF_KEY, etAmount1.getText().toString().trim());
        editor.commit();
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

**Strp2:** *Activity2.xml and activity2.java*

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ncrypted.demorecyclerviewsubitems.Activity2">

    <EditText
        android:hint="Amount2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:id="@+id/etAmount2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:onClick="sendAmount2"
        android:id="@+id/btnSendAmount2"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String PREF_NAME = "prefName";
    private final static String PREF_KEY = "prefKeyActivity2";
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    EditText etAmount2;
    Button btnSendAmount2;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
        etAmount2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmount2);
        btnSendAmount2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendAmount2);
    }

    public void sendAmount2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        if (etAmount2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "please enter amount!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            editor.putString(PREF_KEY, etAmount2.getText().toString().trim());
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**Step3:** *main_activity.xml and MainActivity.java*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ncrypted.demorecyclerviewsubitems.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMain1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Text 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMain2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Text 2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMain1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="btn1"
            android:onClick="expense"/>

        <Button
            android:onClick="income"
            android:id="@+id/btnMain2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="btn2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOpenActivity1, btnOpenActivity2;
    TextView tvText1, tvText2;
    private final static String PREF_NAME = "prefName";
    private final static String PREF_KEY1 = "prefKeyActivity1";
    private final static String PREF_KEY2 = "prefKeyActivity2";
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        btnOpenActivity1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMain1);
        btnOpenActivity2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMain2);
        tvText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMain1);
        tvText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMain2);


    }

    private void getValueFromActivities() {
        if (sharedPref.getString(PREF_KEY1, "").equals("")) {
            tvText1.setText("Value not found!");
        } else {
            tvText1.setText(sharedPref.getString(PREF_KEY1, ""));
        }
        if (sharedPref.getString(PREF_KEY2, "").equals("")) {
            tvText2.setText("Value not found!");
        } else {
            tvText2.setText(sharedPref.getString(PREF_KEY2, ""));
        }
    }

    public void expense(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void income(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getValueFromActivities();

    }
}
```

---

**Step4:** *at last menifest.xml*

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ncrypted.demorecyclerviewsubitems">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="ActivityMain">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity1" android:label="Activity1" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity2" android:label="Activity2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```